# Flutter - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception error

Tags: java, android, flutter

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:parseReleaseLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_api_headers:androidApis'.

> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

> Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-32\android.jar.

> invalid END header (bad central directory offset)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Can you provide the logs that you get when you run your app with a stacktrace as suggested? Also, can you provide more context as to what changes you made to your project recently: packages added, code added/removed, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.